# How to create arithmetic predicates in pyDatalog?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic-programming, datalog, pydatalog

how do I translate this kind of arithmetic predicate to a legal pyDatalog predicate?

add(X, Y, Z) ← X + Y = Z

for example:

?add(5, 7, Z).

the answer should be: add(5, 7, 12).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
add(X, Y, Z) <= (Z == X + Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But when I run add(5,Y,15), it returns "none". It should return 10..

Comment: Indeed, pyDatalog does not have a constraint/equation solver.

Comment: You may try with 3 clauses, just add :  add(X,Y,Z)  <= (X == Z-Y), and add(X,Y,Z)  <= (Y == Z-X)